# Parent's class constructor call error?

Tags: php, constructor

I'm trying to call parent class constructor but it throws an error

`Fatal error: Cannot call constructor`

and the same code was working well before, I didn't change anything and but suddenly don't know what could have happened, It is throwing this error.

I've read some answers on stackoverflow, but they say that your parent class doesn't contain a constructor, well, this is not my case I have constructor in my parent class. Here's my code:

```php
class DB
{
    var $con;

    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once 'configs/dbconfig.php';
        $this->connect();
    }

    function connect()
    {
        try{
            $this->con = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
            $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }catch(PDOException $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

and then I have a class Posts which is extending DB and calling DB's constructor.

```php
class Posts extends DB
{
    var $user_id;

    public function __construct($user_id)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }

    function get_posts($search,$pages,$since_id=0,$max_id=false,$count=20,$status='active')
    {
        $extra = '';
        if($search) $extra .= " AND text LIKE CONCAT('%',:search,'%')";
        if(!empty($pages)) $extra .= " AND page IN('".implode("','", $pages)."')";
        if(!empty($status) && $status != 'all') $extra .= " AND status=:status";

        $max_id = ($max_id) ? $max_id : time();

        $sqlCommand = "SELECT id,pid,text,media,media_url,type,name,u_id,username,user_profile_url,user_photo_url,post_url,date,status,source,page_id FROM ".POSTS." WHERE date>=:since_id AND date<=:max_id".$extra." AND user_id=:user_id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $count";
        $params = array(':since_id'=>$since_id,':max_id'=>$max_id,':user_id'=>$this->user_id);
        if($search) $params[':search'] = $search;
        if($status && $status != 'all') $params[':status'] = $status;

        $posts = $this->fetch($sqlCommand,$params);
        return $posts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is with your php version, It must have been changed, please check the version of php and try to update that.

Comment: Thanks @daisy, I changed my php version from 5.5 to 5.6 and It solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a known PHP bug (look [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54631)), try to make a function in `DB` that returns a new `DB` (by calling constructor) and in `Posts` call this function that you created.

Comment: It had been running for last 6 months, and I didn't even make any changes in the code, then why suddenly this error?

Comment: Probably you updated PHP and in the new version you can't do it.

Comment: Downvoter, please mention the reason of downvoting as comment.

Comment: @Syncro I'm using shared hosting, so it may be that the hosting provider must have updated the PHP, well it sounds like the reason. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Well maybe it's a basic silly answer, but did you try 'require'?

Comment: you mean require the file or something?

Comment: I am not the donwvoter. But, I guess, this answer should be a comment instead.

Comment: @BhavikShah As u can see, I'm new to Stackoverflow. But you're right, i should have commented his answer.